# How can I edit the textures live with photoshop?

Tags: texture-painting

I was wondering if there's a way to paint my model in photoshop and apply it in blender in real - time, as it is possible in 3ds max.

Comment: As I understand, the simple answer is no, but you can set up your model to use the images from photoshop and save them, and force reload of images in the blender window. The application of the images depends on how you use photoshop though, and the image type as well.